# use zend_db and doctrine2 simultaneously in zend framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-db

I'm currently working with an existing zend framework 1 project wich uses the Zend_db component to manage persistance of data to the Database.

The project is still under active development, so I would like to start implementing new models via Doctrine(and eventually convert the old ones to Doctrine as well). I don't see this a big problem, The problem comes when i want to define relations to one of the old tables.

For example:

`User` Table using Zend_DB

New `Coupon` Table using Doctrine2 which has a `created_user` column where i want to save the id of the user.

My question, how to represent this in the Doctrine mappings?